# GCP - showing log value or any other data in slack notification

Tags: google-cloud-platform, slack

is it possible to shpw the log value in slack notifiication ? via google cloud console "

steps :
1- crearted a notification channel
2 - connected the slack channel with :

```
/invite @Google Cloud Monitoring
```

3- set a notification channel to the alert policy

then the only message i can get is :

```
constant title 

logging/user/test for project-id Cloud Function labels  XXX is above the threshold of 0.000 with a value of 1.000.
```

how can i control the data ? i would like to show the real log payload or log text or smth like that